# Amazon Cognito Assigning IAM Roles to Groups in user pool and integration with Identity Pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-cognito

I am trying to use newly added User Groups in User Pool and integrate the same with Federated Identities.

I followed these steps:

1. Create Groups in user pool with roles created in IAM having separate
   policies
2. Create User and add them to user groups
3. Create an Identity Pool and add that Cognito provider under
   **Authentication providers** using app id and client id.

   Here I don't get **Authenticated role selection** under which I have to select **Choose role from token**
   [image: Step 3]
4. I Save Changes and generate the default policies for authenticated and unauthenticated users
5. After the Identity Pool creation i edit it to get **Authenticated role selection** and select **Choose role from token** and save it.
   [image: Step 4]
6. After saving the changes if I go back to edit it i see **Use default role** is selected.
   [image: Step 5]

Is anyone facing the same problem or I have some errors. The policies and Roles work if I define for authenticated role but it overrides User Group roles.

Comment: We are actively looking into this issue as it happens intermittently for some identity pools and will update as soon as it is fixed.

Comment: @RachitDhall This issue got fixed but i have another error. Whenever I use **Choose role from token** I get an error 
`User Sign-in failed for Amazon Cognito Your User Pools : Basic (classic) flow is not supported with SAML, please use enhanced flow. (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentity; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterException; Request ID: 78d983e0-c862-11e6-b92e-493697812207)`

The Solution i found is using [GetCredentialsForIdentity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetCredentialsForIdentity.html) . But how to implement in mobile.

Comment: Yes, we fixed the earlier issue. What are the settings on your pool?

Comment: @RachitDhall I have created  groups under User Pool and selected different IAM Role while creating. After creating the groups i have added one user in each group.
Then in the Identity Pool settings I have set **Choose role from token**. And now when I am signing in those user from that user pool in the mobile hub sample app I am getting that error I mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: Hi, How I get  Identity Pool id from role defined in group of cognito user ?