# Got "Basic (classic) flow is not supported with SAML" while trying to get open id in AWS cognito

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to get open id from username and password that are stored in my cognito user's pool. I used the following configuration, and I got the following error's message:

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the GetOpenIdToken operation: Basic (classic) flow is not supported with SAML, please use enhanced flow.

[image]

I used "Use default role" before, and everything worked fine.
This is the authentication code written in python:

```
import boto3
import datetime
from dateutil.tz import tzlocal

idp = boto3.client("cognito-idp")
identity = boto3.client("cognito-identity")

# login into user pool
response = idp.admin_initiate_auth(AuthFlow='ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH', UserPoolId='us-east-1_4xnGZyQWy', AuthParameters={'USERNAME':'admin', 'PASSWORD':'Ka12345'}, ClientId='25pafveaaladb2qalfh3i7s4h9')

logins = {
    "cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_4xkGZxQWy":response["AuthenticationResult"]["IdToken"]
}

# get identity_id
get_id_response = identity.get_id(IdentityPoolId="us-east-1:bfd63186-8e01-462a-8a5b-db58d7d4af2a", Logins=logins)
identity_id = get_id_response["IdentityId"]

# get credentials
credentials = identity.get_credentials_for_identity(IdentityId=identity_id, Logins=logins)
print(credentials)
credentials["Credentials"]["Expiration"] = str(credentials["Credentials"]["Expiration"])

# get open id token
oidToken = identity.get_open_id_token(IdentityId=identity_id, Logins=logins)

output = dict()
output["identityId"] = identity_id
output["token"] = oidToken["Token"]
output["credentials"] = credentials["Credentials"]

print(output)
```

I've found here: 
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41247295/amazon-cognito-assigning-iam-roles-to-groups-in-user-pool-and-integration-with-i#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41247295/amazon-cognito-assigning-iam-roles-to-groups-in-user-pool-and-integration-with-i#_=_) 
There is a guy said that I need to add "CustomRoleArn" into "get_credentials_for_identity". I did it but still got error. So what I need to do to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I finally found that enhanced auth flow doesn't need to get open ID. We only need to get credential with role arn from username
for more information, refer to this link
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authentication-flow.html
at "Enhanced (Simplified) Authflow" section