# Cognito User Pool Groups not working with different roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to achieve the following:
I have a web application that needs different user permissions for some menus and calls to the API gateway.

I have done the following:
- Set up a user pool with 2 groups ( *Group 1* and *Group 2* )
- Assigned users to those groups
- Set up 2 policies ( *Policy 1* and *Policy 2*, where policy 1 is the default policy in *authenticated role* in fed. identites)
- Set up the correct trust policies in the roles
- In *federated identities*, under *authentication providers*, I have set *authenticated role* selection to *choose role from token*

On the front, I have decoded the *ID token* and verified that the *cognito:groups* etc are correct when initialising a login.

So group 1 is the looser policy allowing everything, and policy 2 is the stricter policy that should not allow calls to a certain resource in API gateway.

But when I assign a user to a group 2 which has the stricter Policy 2, the user still seems to use the policy 1 which allows everything. What am I doing wrong here?

I have the same problem as [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41247295/amazon-cognito-assigning-iam-roles-to-groups-in-user-pool-and-integration-with-i) and done exactly what it says but still no progress

Comment: Having the same problem here. Did you solve it?

Comment: No, I ended up solving it in another way...I incorrectly used cognito as an authorizer. I shouldn't have used an authorizer at all but instead used AWS_IAM for the API gateway. Then I do a refresh credentials and refresh session before each call to the API gateway where I assume the correct role with the correct ARN (saved from earlier login). Little tricky but it works. Hope this helps you!

Comment: Hey thanks for the anwser. I've also solved it yesterday after I'd asked you by going the same way. If other people might be interested I've posted my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48540390/aws-restrict-cognito-authorized-user-to-specific-lambda-functions

Answer (score 9):

Check the role assigned to the user group has a `trust relationship`. It needs this so it can assume the role of the federated identity provider.

You can build an appropriate role for the User pool groups role by doing this:

- Open AWS console
- Get to IAM section
- Pick roles
- Pick web identity
- Choose Amazon Cognito
- Paste in your Identity pool id (the federated one)
- Click next
- Now add/create policies you need for the user group, like S3 access, or whatever.
- Give the role a name and save it.
- Go to your User Pool group, edit it and assign the role just created.
- Open the Federated Identity
- Set the Authenticated role selection dropbox to `Choose role from token`
- Optionally set `Role resolution` to `DENY`

References:

[Fine grained auth](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/building-fine-grained-authorization-using-amazon-cognito-user-pools-groups/)

[Role based access control](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/role-based-access-control.html)

Comment: You beauty! This comment solved a hard problem I had where I couldn't assume a group role for user when using their token. The second last step did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a silly question, but have you assigned an IAM Role to the Cognito User Pools Group?

Further, I would opt for a more restrictive policy precedence. You should apply "normal user" policies as the Authenticated Role and more "admin user" policies as roles to be assumed by users belonging to specific groups.

Similar to:

**Group:** Admins (Policy A attached) (Precedence 0)
**Group:** Users (Policy B attached) (Precedence 10)

**Authenticated Role:** Policy B

Comment: Yes I have assigned a role to the user group